# Does $ \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^{\alpha}}dx$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, integration

Does this integral converge or diverge?

$$ \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^{\alpha}}dx\qquad (\alpha \geq 0) $$

I was stuck when solved this problem this way:

$ \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^{\alpha}}dx = \int_0^{1} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^{\alpha}}dx + \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^{\alpha}}dx =I_1 +I_2$

1) $\qquad I_1=\int_0^{1} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^{\alpha}}dx=\int_0^{1} f(x)dx$; $\qquad g(x)=\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}e^{-x}=1$ so:

+) If $\quad\alpha<1 \Longrightarrow \int_0^{1} \frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}dx $ converge $\Longrightarrow \int_0^{1} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^{\alpha}}dx$ converge

+) If $\quad\alpha \geq 1 \Longrightarrow \int_0^{1} \frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}dx $ diverge $\Longrightarrow \int_0^{1} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^{\alpha}}dx$ diverge

2) $\qquad I_1=\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^{\alpha}}dx$; $\qquad g(x)=\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} e^{-x}=0$

1) If $\quad\alpha>1 \Longrightarrow \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}dx$ diverge $\Longrightarrow \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^{\alpha}}dx$ deverge

2) If $\quad a \leq 1$ then I stucked here

Comment: Welcome to MSE. As stated, this question could be typed into a calculator with no need for human interaction; as such, I am voting to close this as off-topic. Please [edit] your question to include your thoughts and what tools you think are relevant.

Comment: @T.Bongers I have edited the question

Comment: $\displaystyle\Gamma\left(1 - \alpha\right)\,,\quad\Re\left(\alpha\right) < 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for $\forall \alpha \ge 0$ you have $x^{-\alpha} \le 1$ in $(1,\infty)$ therefore

$$ \int_1^\infty x^{-\alpha}e^{-x} dx \le \int_1^\infty e^{-x} dx = e^{-1} $$

which indeed converges.

The rest is checking for convergence on $(0,1)$ which you've already done.